# php foreach with counter loop within it

Tags: php, arrays

I have a lot of code but basically its a foreach loop with values collected and $i is the dynamic number.

I want to get a bunch of attachments from a json and have following inside the foreach

```
<?php

$i=0;
foreach($attribs->contentblocks->add_to_content as $count) { 

if($attribs->contentblocks->add_to_content[$i]=='3') { 

// other code goes here

?>

<?php for($a = 1; $a < 30; ++$a){ ?>

<?php echo $attribs->contentblocks->blockfile[$a][$i];?>

<?php } ?>

<?php $i++; }} ?>
```

But... it wont work. If i replace [$a] with an actual number like 1 or 2 or 3 it works.

How do i add the dynamic $a number into that line to work with my $i as well?

Cheers
John

Comment: what do you mean foreach loop? thats a for loop, and on our side, there is nothing wrong with it

Comment: I have a foreach loop and want the coiunter loop to work inside it - 29times

Comment: did you try to var_dump($a);

Comment: You want `$a` as incremented number or
 `$i
`

Comment: @AdamSinclair the var dump returns int(1) int(2) int(3) int(4) etc...

Comment: you need to add $i++ before your foreach loop completed.

Comment: @MoeedFarooqui $i increments per block - $a increments from 1-29 within that block.I want to create this attribs->contentblocks->blockfile1[$i],attribs->contentblocks->blockfile2[$i],etc..

Comment: I dont undertsand why my question is bad? please explain what is an approprtae way to ask my question. What does teh minus one even mean in this context please?

Comment: what if instead of `<?php echo $attribs->contentblocks->blockfile[$a][$i];?>` you got `<?php echo $attribs->contentblocks->blockfile[$1][$i];?>`

Comment: @AdamSinclair im not quite sure how that would work, because a number wil just break that. Basically all i want is attribs->contentblocks->blockfile1[$i],attribs->contentblocks->blockfile2[$i],et‌​c.. Replacing the number with $a - I have tried several ways to append the $a but no kluck. I have tried .$a. {$a} $a but none worked

Comment: What if you change the variable name ?

Comment: @Adam thanks for sticking around - Ghost got me on the right track :)

Comment: Ok now I see what you were looking for! Glad you found :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then kindly try this one if you hav said in the comments, `blockfile1, blockfile2, ... etc.`:

```
<?php echo $attribs->contentblocks->{'blockfile'.$a}[$i]; ?>
```

Comment: Thank you! Now i can finish this and have a coconut juice with ice in 120kmh winds. :)

Answer (score 0):

If  you want `$i` as incremented variable. You can achieve this by doing:

```
<?php
$i = 0;
 for($a = 1; $a < 30; ++$a){ ?>

<?php echo $attribs->contentblocks->blockfile[$a][$i];?>

<?php $i++; } ?>
```

Comment: $i is already set as 0 then 1 then 2 - depends on how many blocks there are. The $a is the one that i need to work as it is a loop inside the foreach for $i